# Confirmation of existence of a historical document about French revolution and Lyon?

Tags: french-revolution

The site marxists.org have [this document](https://www.marxists.org/history/france/revolution/1793/lyon.htm), that it is alleged was issued by the Committee of Public Safety of Maximilian Robespierre.

Wikimedia thinks it is real
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:R%C3%A9publique_fran%C3%A7aise,_de_l%27Imprimerie_de_Tournachon-Molin.png#filelinks

Is this document even real, where is the original and how I can cite it?

Comment: Follow the sources at https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul%C3%A8vement_de_Lyon_contre_la_Convention_nationale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item you are linking to seems to be a translation of a poster/proclamation.

You can find an original in the [digital collection](https://www.digitalcollections.manchester.ac.uk/view/PR-R-00002-07312/1) at the University of Manchester, UK.

[image]

The above image has the following copyright claim

> Images and Metadata made available for download are licensed under a
> Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International License
> (CC BY-NC 4.0).

Comment: Since the motivation appears to be to point the copyright details out to the poster, because it seemed relevant to their question, all that copyright info is reasonable. I hope others won't look at this and think they need to start tacking on that level of copyright text around routine pictures though. The "(CC BY-NC 4.0)" would be reasonable for typical uses, if one feels it is needed.

Comment: Yes, I did include the extra detail on the copyright since the user asked how to cite the information.